# Filtering data frame using str.contains('') but with an exception

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to filter out rows in my data frame column `'PRODUCT'` while using `str.contains('DE')`. `DE` ranges from `DE001` up to `DE999`.

How do I filter out `DE998` and `DE999`? I have been trying this code but I can't seem to figure out a way to remove `DE998` and `DE999` without having to do it manually on another line.

I am using `df2[df2['PRODUCT'].str.contains("DE")]`. Can anyone suggest a code for this or a more efficient way to do this? Thank you for answering. Sorry, still a newbie programmer.

Comment: You want to ignore every line with `DE998` and `DE999`, but keep every other entry (like `DE001`)?

Comment: Yes, that is what I'm aiming for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create 2 masks: one testing the first 2 characters and the other testing the entire string. For the second condition, we can use `~` to indicate a negative condition. Then combine the 2 Boolean masks with the `&` operator.

```
mask1 = df2['PRODUCT'].str[:2] == 'DE'
mask2 = ~df2['PRODUCT'].isin(['DE998', 'DE999'])

res = df2[mask1 & mask2]
```

Comment: Worked out well. Thanks for answering!

Comment: @PJG, No problem, in around 10 mins you can accept the answer if you wish (green tick on left).